# Error with automatic payment methods (using Payment Element) Stripe

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Payment details were collected through Stripe Elements using automatic payment methods and cannot be confirmed with a Payment Intent configured with payment_method_types.

What did I do wrong?

Here's how I create the payment intents on my backend:

```
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: esimPrice,
      currency: 'usd',
      customer: stripeCustomerId,
      automatic_payment_methods: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      metadata: {
        firebaseUID: auth.uid,
      },
    });
```

Here's my CheckoutFormStripe.tsx in my frontend(I confirm the payment in the useEffect):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Elements, useStripe, useElements, PaymentElement } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { PaymentMethod, StripeElementsOptions, loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
import {
  CardElement,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth, getUserData } from "../services/firebase";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_TEST_KEY || ""
);

const options: StripeElementsOptions = {
  mode: 'payment',
  currency: 'usd',
  amount: 1600
};

const CheckoutForm = () => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const functions = getFunctions();
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  //const [paymentMethod, setPaymentMethod] = useState<PaymentMethod | null>(null);
  const [paymentError, setPaymentError] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [paymentStatus, setPaymentStatus] = useState("");
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  
  const esimPackageId = "change-30days-5gb"; // temp
  const esimCountryCode = "US";


  useEffect(() => {
    const confirmPayment = async () => {
      if (!clientSecret) {
        console.error('Client secret is missing');
        return;
      }
      const paymentElement = elements?.getElement(PaymentElement);
  
      if (!stripe || !elements || !email || !paymentElement) {
        return;
      }
      const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
        elements: elements,
        clientSecret,
        confirmParams: {
          // Return URL where the customer should be redirected after the PaymentIntent is confirmed.
          return_url: 'http://localhost/myesims',
        },
      })
      console.log(error.message);
      if(error) handleError(error);
    }

    confirmPayment();
    
  }, [clientSecret]);

  const fetchEmail = async () => {
    if(user) {
      const userData = await getUserData(user.uid);
      setEmail(userData?.email ?? '');
    }
  }

  const handleError = (error: any) => {
    const errorMessage = error.message ?? 'An unexpected error occurred.';
    console.log(errorMessage);
    setPaymentError(errorMessage);
    //setPaymentMethod(null);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchEmail();
  }, [user]);



  const handleSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const paymentElement = elements?.getElement(PaymentElement);

    if (!stripe || !elements || !email || !paymentElement) {
      return;
    }
  
    setIsLoading(true);

    // Trigger form validation and wallet collection
    const {error: submitError} = await elements.submit();
    if (submitError) {
      handleError(submitError);
      return;
    }

    setPaymentError(null);
    //setPaymentMethod(paymentMethod);

    const createStripePaymentIntent = httpsCallable(
      functions,
      "createStripePaymentIntent"
    );
    createStripePaymentIntent({
      esimPackageId: esimPackageId,
      esimCountryCode: esimCountryCode
    })
    .then(async (res) => {
      // Handle the response
      console.log(res);
      if (res && res.data) {
        const client_secret = res.data;
        console.log(clientSecret);
        setClientSecret(client_secret as string);
        // Use the clientSecret and Elements instance to confirm the setup
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle the error
      console.log(error);
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement />
      <button disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements} id="submit">
        <span id="button-text">
          {isLoading ? <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div> : "Pay now"}
        </span>
      </button>
      {paymentError && <p>{paymentError}</p>}
    </form>
  );
};

const CheckoutFormStripe = () => (
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
    <CheckoutForm />
  </Elements>
);

export default CheckoutFormStripe;
```

Also, just to make sure, for now the options (StripeElementsOptions) I used are for testing but in general the amount in it should be equal to the amount in I used when I create the payment intent right?

I have tried following the documentations of Stripe and youtube videos but there aren't much info because I am using the Payment Elements which is considered pretty new.

Answer (score 3):

That specific error is raised by Stripe when your code calls `confirmPayment()` client-side but your PaymentIntent is configured with `payment_method_types` instead of having `automatic_payment_methods[enabled]: true` set. The server-side code you shared seems correct here but it's likely that this isn't the real code you're running.

I'd recommend adding logs to your code to track the exact PaymentIntent you're creating and making sure it has that feature enabled on it. You can look it up in your Dashboard for example and check the creation request in its Logs section to make sure that parameter is enabled. Otherwise reach out to Stripe support team with those details so that they can show you what went wrong.

Comment: I actually do have logs and according to the logs and I am running that exact code, any more ideas?

Comment: No, I'd recommend reaching out to Stripe who can help you as they can look at your code and the order of requests you're making

Answer (score 0):

Faced same error today, so let it be here:
Property **mode** of **options: StripeElementsOptions** can be "payment" or "setup" or "subscription"
see docs -  https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_without_intent#stripe_elements_no_intent-options-mode 
It should match payment type of payment intent, e.g. payment intent created for recurring payment - mode must be "subscription".